# How to get a shortcut string from TShortCut in an action?

Tags: delphi, keyboard-shortcuts, tactionmanager

I'm using a `TActionManager`, where each action has a keyboard `ShortCut` assigned to it. I would like to display text which represents the keyboard shortcut to the user. For example, `F4` or `Ctrl+F` or `Ctrl+Shift+S`. However, the `TShortCut` is defined as:

```
type
  TShortCut = Low(Word)..High(Word);
```

How can I obtain a user-readable string which represents the shortcut assigned to an action?

Comment: This is well documented: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TShortCut

Comment: @David This appears to be a case of documentation not matching - I was looking in the docs matching my Delphi version (even though it should apply for all versions since it existed) - the XE7 docs mention nothing like the XE8 docs do: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Classes.TShortCut

Comment: True. But you are but a single link away from the topic that has the information. Follow the link to http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Menus.ShortCut

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm answering my own question Q/A style.

There's a built-in function for this called `ShortCutToText()` which converts any given `TShortCut` into a readable representation. On the other hand, there's also `TextToShortCut()` which works the other way around, converting any string into a `TShortCut`, given it's a valid shortcut value.

Comment: The functions exist in [unit `Vcl.Menus`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Menus.ShortCutToText), they're not built-in like i.e. `System.SetLength()`.